# Retrieving Root Data From Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Actually I Want To Retrieve My Root Data From Firebase Database**

This Is What I Tried-

```
 mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
               for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   UserInformation currentUser = data.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                   mUser.add(currentUser);


               }
           } else {
               showToast("Empty Data");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

But It Gives Error

Comment: What error? That's the most important part of a question... please add it to the question details.

Comment: What's the error from your logcat?